# Matching array of objects with array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have 2 arrays:

```
arr1: ["1","2"]
arr2: [{id: 1, color: "green"}, {id: 2, color: "yellow"}, {id: 3, color: "red"}]
```

And I want to obtain:

```
result: [{id: 1, color: "green"}, {id: 2, color: "yellow"}]
```

I am trying with

```
arr2.filter(
  e => arr1.indexOf(e.id) !== -1
);
```

But result is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that as your inputs have different types(`id` is a number but `arr1` has strings), this `arr1.indexOf(e.id) !== -1` will always be false.

Convert one of them to a number like this:

```js
const arr1 = ["1","2"]
const arr2 = [{id: 1, color: "green"}, {id: 2, color: "yellow"}, {id: 3, color: "red"}]

const result = arr2.filter(el => arr1.some(aEl => el.id === +aEl))
console.log(result)
```

Alternatively, you can convert the ids to strings and use your existing code:

```js
const arr1 = ["1", "2"],
  arr2 = [{
    id: 1,
    color: "green"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    color: "yellow"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    color: "red"
  }],

  result = arr2.filter(
    e => arr1.indexOf(e.id.toString()) !== -1
  );

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to get the result.

```js
const arr1 = ['1', '2'];
const arr2 = [
  { id: 1, color: 'green' },
  { id: 2, color: 'yellow' },
  { id: 3, color: 'red' },
];

const ret = arr2.filter((x) => arr1.some((y) => +y === x.id));
console.log(ret);
```

Another solution using [`Set Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
const arr1 = ['1', '2'];
const arr2 = [
  { id: 1, color: 'green' },
  { id: 2, color: 'yellow' },
  { id: 3, color: 'red' },
];
const set = new Set(arr1);
const ret = arr2.filter((x) => set.has(x.id.toString()));
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is may be with `.includes()` method.

```js
const arr1 =  ["1","2"]
const arr2 = [{id: 1, color: "green"}, {id: 2, color: "yellow"}, {id: 3, color: "red"}]

const result = arr2.filter(n => arr1.includes(String(n.id)));
console.log(result);
```